# A word to describe things that reduce control

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing about the concept of "that which has a chance of preventing the intended or desired result". I refer to it frequently and it's very inconvenient to define it every time so I need to find a phrase or (preferably) single word to use as a label for it.

I've considered terms like "obstacle" or "challenge" but some obstacles can be reliably overcome and the word challenge implies that skill is a factor. So far I've used the word "uncertainty" but I think it's too extensive as it applies to things that have no bearing on the intended or desired result.

Is there a word or phrase to describe that which reduces control or produces the opposite of control?

**Edit**: I need to use the word consistently in several sentences. So let me give you a paragraph instead: "When a users interact with software there are always **X**. If you're designing a software tool you want to minimize **X** to provide the user a reliable tool. But if you're making a game you need **X** to make it exciting for the player."

If you replace **X** with *"things that which have a chance of preventing the intended or desired result"* you get the correct meaning but the sentence becomes incredibly awkward. It's hard to find a word/phrase with a good match since it's so precise. If there's no word like that I'll use the closest thing.

Comment: Are you looking for: 'hindrance' or 'impediment' or 'constraints' or 'barrier' or 'obstruction'?
Impotent means state in which you lack of power or control.

Comment: Please provide a sentence into which the word can be put.

Comment: I have used *friction* in this way, to describe the amount of hindrance towards getting a job done.     You seem to want an uncountable term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest ***unpredictability***. *Unpredictability* is not good for non-gaming software, but it is desirable while creating gaming software.

**Unpredictability** [**<sub>Oxford Dictionary</sub>**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unpredictability)

> ***Meaning:*** Inability to be predicted; changeability
>
> > ***Usage:*** "the constant element of unpredictability keeps the show fresh."

Your paragraph:

> > "When a users interact with software there are always ***unpredictability***. If you're designing a software tool you want to minimize ***unpredictability*** to provide the user a reliable tool. But if you're making a game you need ***unpredictability*** to make it exciting for the player."

Answer (score 1):

"Difficulty" might fit.

It's defined in OLO as state of being difficult or something that is difficult.

> Difficult
>   1.Needing much effort or skill to accomplish, deal with, or understand.
>   1.1 Characterized by or causing hardships or problems.
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/difficult)

It seems to match your need when you say:

> things that which have a chance of preventing the intended or desired
>   result

Filling the blanks of your example sentence results in the following:

> "When a users interact with software there are always [difficulties]. If you're
>   designing a software tool you want to minimize [difficulties] to provide the user a
>   reliable tool. But if you're making a game you need [difficulty] to make it
>   exciting for the player."

Comment: I think difficulty is too narrow because it implies that skills is a factor which isn't always the case. It's the same reason I didn't want to use "challenge".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about a level of randomness. The technical term is *noise*. It hinders control and introduces a measure of unpredictability.

> **noise** *noun*
> 2.1 Random fluctuations that obscure or do not contain meaningful data or other information.
> ‘over half the magnitude of the differences came from noise in the data’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/noise)
>
> In experimental sciences, **noise** can refer to any random fluctuations of data that hinders perception of an expected signal.
> [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise); emphasis, mine